# memory committed remains the same after all things are cleared

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a GUI application that contains a CView used to display a lot of simulated ants.

I create a vector of shared_ptr to hold the simulation controllers (there are many if I aim to open more views). Each of the controllers contains many shared_ptr's that are cyclic-dependent.

When I start my simulation, I turn on my task manager and see the program memory increasing until the program stops (e.g 3000MB). I close all views and also call the created Reset method to clear all containers or vectors used to store input and output data as well as the controllers. Yet I still see that 3000MB not getting changed back to 3MB or any other similarly smaller number, for example.

I am having a memory leak right ? Because if I start to run my simulation again, the committed or used memory as said gets changed into larger and larger numbers while I am thinking it should be reset to the lowest possible number right after clearing methods are invoked.

Comment: Please post come code. For example, "call the created Reset method to clear all containers or vectors used to store input and output data as well as the controllers" doesn't really tell us anything except that you think you're doing something that will free and uncommit memory.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Cyclic shared pointers can end up not being deleted. Consider the following:

```
struct Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_foo;
}

std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo1 = std::make_shared<Foo>();
std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo>();

foo1.m_foo = foo2;
foo2.m_foo = foo1;
```

After all that, `foo1` and `foo2` are pointing at - and own - each other. So neither shared pointer will ever end up with a reference count of zero, and neither will be deleted. That might be what's going on with your code if your shared pointers are cyclically linked.